# Use Chrome Extension API to get files in a directory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I want to make a chrome new tab extension that is customizable, and so far you can add images via modifying a cryptic JS array. Is there any way to scan it with the chrome filesystem API or Regular Expressions?

Comment: No such API, but you can write a simple native OS app that lists any directory and is installed separately so you can connect to it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: @wOxxOm I need it to work on Chromebooks and run on native JS.

Comment: ChromeOS can run more stuff nowadays, for example android apps.

Comment: Maybe i should analyze how infinity new tab did it?

Comment: Inspecting the existing solutions should be your first choice.

Comment: Anyway, Infinity new tab did it by just getting the files. I guess I should just use an array and let them add files then.